# Accelerometer not working on Android-wear emulator

Tags: android, emulation, accelerometer, wear-os, acceleration

```
sensor set acceleration 9.77621:0:0
```

is not working for Android wear emulator..

I have register event for sensor value change, but not getting any call back.

is it suppose to work differently then phone? (using mac)